# Cloudinary creating a thumbnail on image upload

Tags: image-processing, cdn, cloudinary

Cloudinary is generating a `thumbnail` for each image upload on their service. In fact, I found out that 1 uploaded image means:

- 1 resource image
- 1 derivative image
- 2 transformations

I was wondering whether it was possible or not to disable the "thumbnail feature".

Oh ... BTW, can someone explains why 2 transformations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudinary generates the thumbnails only if they are displayed in the Media library. In other words, when you upload via the API, then no thumbnail is created (unless it's viewed afterwards in the Media library).

Regarding the count - Cloudinary counts all processed images, which includes both uploads and image manipulations.
Have a look at the following for more information:

https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/203619481-How-does-Cloudinary-count-transformations-

https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/203125631-How-does-Cloudinary-count-my-plan-s-quotas-and-what-does-every-quota-mean-

Comment: What I understand: 1 upload = 1 resource image + 1 transformation and first viewing of an uploaded file in the Media library = 1 derivative image + 1 transformation. Is that correct?